# C: Initializing a dynamically typed 2D matrix inside another function

Tags: c, matrix, dynamic, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to create 3 matrices which are dynamically typed (int, float, double) for the purpose of matrix multiplication. I've created a void** "typed" container for each matrix in the main, then passing them (as void***) into an init function to be malloc'd based on user selections for the type. The code below compiles, but I am getting a segmentation fault after one iteration of the j loop, and I can't figure out for the life of me why this happens. Similarly if I were to do the initialization in a separate 2-deep loop (take out j-loop from malloc loop), then the segmentation error occurs after one iteration of the i-loop still.

Is this even a good way to accomplish my goal of dynamic-typed matrix multiplication? Thank you very much for the help.

```
void initMat(int type, int matSize, void ***matA, void ***matB, void ***matC)
{
    int i, j, k;

    switch(type) {
        case 0 :
        *matA = malloc(matSize * sizeof(int*));
        *matB = malloc(matSize * sizeof(int*));
        *matC = malloc(matSize * sizeof(int*));
        for (i = 0; i < matSize; i++) {
            *matA[i] = malloc(matSize * sizeof(int));
            *matB[i] = malloc(matSize * sizeof(int));
            *matC[i] = malloc(matSize * sizeof(int));
            for (j = 0; j < matSize; j++) {
                *(int*)matA[i][j] = rand()/RAND_MAX * 10;
                *(int*)matB[i][j] = rand()/RAND_MAX * 10;
                *(int*)matC[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
        break;

        case 1 :
        // with float, double, etc.
        break;

        default :
        printf("Invalid case.\n" );
    }
}

int main()
{
    int type = 0;
    int size = 0;
    void **matA, **matB, **matC;

    int sizes[6] = {3, 4, 5};
    int matSize = sizes[size];
    printf("The selected matrix size is: %d. \n", matSize); //allows user to select matrix size

    initMat(type, matSize, &matA, &matB, &matC);

//  displayMat(matSize, matA);

}
```

Comment: why are you using `*(int*)` ?

Comment: Use GDB and check where your program is not giving the desired output or it is getting crashed

Comment: like [this](https://ideone.com/igYfQQ)

Comment: @hassanarafat it's to cast the void pointer into a int point before dereferencing it

Comment: @VivekSingh I used checkpoints to narrow down the problem to which exact iteration the seg fault occurs. And the thing is that the implementation is exactly like answers from other questions of similar style (except with the matrix passing and dynamic typing - so I can only assume it's one of those reasons messing it up)

Comment: matA[i][j] is not allocated any memory, it's pointing to no where.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY wow I tried that out and indeed it worked as expected, thanks a lot! It makes sense why yours would work, but could you please explain why mine didn't? why is that passing one reference-level less, and creating the second layer of arrays locally allows it to work as expected?

Comment: It is necessary to fit the _type_. Also, I will not create it locally.

Comment: @hassanarafat oh wait I think that's the problem - I got confused thinking that the offset [i][j] will go to the pointer one layer down...

Comment: @BLUEPIXY sorry - the whole pointer thing is still taking some time to become intuitive with. you're right, it's not local, because you're working directly with the memory location pointed to by *matA, which is also why it stays once the function returns. let me think about this all a bit more, but thank you very much for the help

Comment: @M.Lee Pointer's are powerful, but they can be a pain in the ass

Comment: @hassanarafat haha yea. I've been drawing a lot of address pictures to wrap my head around it, but the model in my mind is coming together. Just to confirm, if I declare int *A = malloc(r*sizeof(int)), then A is a pointer containing an address, *A is an integer at the address stored in A, and A[1] is the integer which is stored 1*sizeof(int) offset from the address stored in A...right?
so in a way when you write A[1] you're dereferencing A in a way, and so if B was declared int **B then B[1][2] dereferences B twice.

Comment: @M.Lee That is correct, in your case all you need for your matrix is `**void` no need for `***void`. One more thing, when you do a `int *x = malloc(sizeof(int));` it allocates memory and returns a pointer, it doesn't allocate where your pointer pointed to originally, it changes the value of `x` to the newly allocated memory

Comment: @M.Lee I added an answer with an explanation, please check it out

Comment: @yes, I understand that it'll overwrite the previous pointer of x, so even if it was a void pointer before, it will now be pointing to an int (or a pointer to an int, w/e). Thanks for the confirmation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To work with dynamically allocated 2d arrays, correct pointer types should be used. `(int **)` is a pointer to a pointer, pointing to the first element of an array of pointers which themselves point to disparate allocations. The result of this sort of code is a jagged array, but not a 2d array. The allocated memory is not guaranteed to be contiguous (as array allocations must be):

```
size_t num_rows = 3;
size_t num_cols = 5;

int **jagged_arr = malloc(sizeof *jagged_arr * num_rows);

for (size_t i = 0; i < num_rows; i++) {
    jagged_arr[i] = malloc(sizeof *jagged_arr[i] * num_cols);
}
```

One possibility is to simply allocate storage for a 1d array, and calculate offsets into this array from 2d array indices. This works fine, but the result is not a 2d array:

```
size_t num_elems = num_rows * num_cols;
int *simulated_2d_arr = malloc(sizeof *simulated_2d_arr * num_elems);
```

This can't be indexed as a 2d array, but the 1d index can be calculated from the number of columns and the 2d array indices:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < num_rows; i++) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < num_cols; j++) {
        simulated_2d_arr[i * num_cols + j] = i * num_cols + j;
    }
}
```

Both of these approaches have their uses, but they suffer from a disadvantage in that the resulting arrays can't be passed to functions which are meant to work with 2d arrays. That is, consider a function to print a 2d array, such as:

```
void print_2d_arr(size_t rows, size_t cols, int arr[][cols])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            printf("%5d", arr[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

This function will work for something like:

```
int real_2d_arr[2][3] = { { 1, 2, 3 },
                          { 4, 5, 6 } };
```

But it will not work for the earlier `jagged_arr`:

> expected ‘int (*)[(sizetype)(cols)]’ but argument is of type ‘int **’

or for `simulated_2d_arr`:

> expected ‘int (*)[(sizetype)(cols)]’ but argument is of type ‘int *’

The correct type to use when dynamically allocating 2d arrays is seen in the above error messages. For a 2d array of `int`s, that would be `int (*)[]`. This is the type that a 2d array decays to in most expressions, including function calls. So, to dynamically allocate a 2d array of `int`s, this would work:

```
size_t num_rows = 3;
size_t num_cols = 5;
int (*array_2d)[num_cols] = malloc(sizeof *array_2d * num_rows);
```

This allocates space for `num_rows` arrays of `num_cols` `int`s. Note that this does not create a VLA, but the VLA *type* is used. Of course, VLAs were introduced back in C99, but were made optional in C11 (though still widely supported).

As for the dynamic type part of your question, one option would be to create an `enum` to hold type identifiers, and pass one of these enumeration constants to whatever functions need them. These functions will need to accept `(void *)` arguments, which will be appropriately converted based on the type enumeration constant. This is a little more involved, but here is an example program. Note that the `print_array()` function works for both the dynamically allocated arrays, and for a statically sized array. Also note that there is no need for triple, or even double indirection!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum Type { CHAR,
            INT,
            FLOAT,
            DOUBLE };

void * get_array(enum Type type, size_t rows, size_t cols);
void init_array(enum Type type, size_t rows, size_t cols, void *arr);
void print_array(enum Type type, size_t rows, size_t cols, void *arr);

int main(void)
{
    char (*arr_char)[5] = get_array(CHAR, 4, 5);
    int (*arr_int)[5] = get_array(INT, 4, 5);
    double (*arr_double)[5] = get_array(DOUBLE, 4, 5);

    int arr_static[][3] = { { 1, 2, 3 },
                            { 4, 5, 6 },
                            { 7, 8, 9 } };

    if (arr_char) {                           // check for null pointer
        init_array(CHAR, 4, 5, arr_char);
        puts("4x5 array of char");
        print_array(CHAR, 4, 5, arr_char);
        putchar('\n');
    }

    if (arr_int) {                            // check for null pointer
        init_array(INT, 4, 5, arr_int);
        puts("4x5 array of int");
        print_array(INT, 4, 5, arr_int);
        putchar('\n');
    }

    if (arr_double) {                         // check for null pointer
        init_array(DOUBLE, 4, 5, arr_double);
        puts("4x5 array of double");
        print_array(DOUBLE, 4, 5, arr_double);
        putchar('\n');
    }

    puts("Statically sized 3x3 array of int");
    print_array(INT, 3, 3, arr_static);
    putchar('\n');

    /* Cleanup */
    free(arr_char);
    free(arr_int);
    free(arr_double);

    return 0;
}

/* Returns null pointer on allocation failure */
void *get_array(enum Type type, size_t rows, size_t cols)
{
    size_t array_sz = 0;
    void *ret = NULL;

    switch (type) {
    case CHAR:
        array_sz = sizeof (char) * rows * cols;
        break;
    case INT:
        array_sz = sizeof (int) * rows * cols;
        break;
    case FLOAT:
        array_sz = sizeof (float) * rows * cols;
        break;
    case DOUBLE:
        array_sz = sizeof (double) * rows * cols;
        break;
    default:
        fprintf(stderr, "Unrecognized type in get_array()");
    }

    if (array_sz) {
        ret = malloc(array_sz);
    }

    return ret;
}

void init_array(enum Type type, size_t rows, size_t cols, void *arr)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            int offset = i * cols + j;
            switch (type) {
            case CHAR:
            {
                char (*array_char)[cols] = arr;
                array_char[i][j] = 'a' + offset;
                break;
            }
            case INT:
            {
                int (*array_int)[cols] = arr;
                array_int[i][j] = 0 + offset;
                break;
            }
            case FLOAT:
            {
                float (*array_float)[cols] = arr;
                array_float[i][j] = 0.0 + offset;
                break;
            }
            case DOUBLE:
            {
                double (*array_double)[cols] = arr;
                array_double[i][j] = 0.0 + offset;
                break;
            }
            default:
                fprintf(stderr, "Unrecognized type in get_array()");
            }
        }
    }
}

void print_array(enum Type type, size_t rows, size_t cols, void *arr)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                switch (type) {
            case CHAR:
            {
                char (*array_char)[cols] = arr;
                printf("%3c", array_char[i][j]);
                break;
            }
            case INT:
            {
                int (*array_int)[cols] = arr;
                printf("%5d", array_int[i][j]);
                break;
            }
            case FLOAT:
            {
                float (*array_float)[cols] = arr;
                printf("%8.2f", array_float[i][j]);
                break;
            }
            case DOUBLE:
            {
                double (*array_double)[cols] = arr;
                printf("%8.2f", array_double[i][j]);
                break;
            }
            default:
                fprintf(stderr, "Unrecognized type in get_array()");
            }
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Program output:

```
4x5 array of char
  a  b  c  d  e
  f  g  h  i  j
  k  l  m  n  o
  p  q  r  s  t

4x5 array of int
    0    1    2    3    4
    5    6    7    8    9
   10   11   12   13   14
   15   16   17   18   19

4x5 array of double
    0.00    1.00    2.00    3.00    4.00
    5.00    6.00    7.00    8.00    9.00
   10.00   11.00   12.00   13.00   14.00
   15.00   16.00   17.00   18.00   19.00

Statically sized 3x3 array of int
    1    2    3
    4    5    6
    7    8    9
```

Answer (score 1):

I've actually been working on something exactly like this on my own. My advice on how to do this is to actually abandon the way you're doing it. From the looks of it you have an array of pointers (lets say an array of int pointers), and each one of those pointers has an array of its own, basically a variable declared as such `int **exampleMatrix`. There's actually a huge issue with you doing it this way which is cache misses. A better way for you to do this is as follows

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void *initMat(size_t rows, size_t cols, int type);

int main(void){
    int *matrix = initMat();
    free(matrix);
    return 0;
}

void *initMat(size_t rows, size_t cols, int type){
    //check for what type to allocate here
    void *matrix = malloc(sizeof(int)*rows*cols);
    //check for errors here
    return matrix;
}
```

you of course will have to decide if your matrix is row or column major. I hope this makes sense, English isn't my first language and I'm not the best at explaining sometimes. If you need me to explain it better just tell me :)

Comment: Yea this makes sense, I know that this is one way of allocating a 2D matrix, (only one level pointer, and any subsequent get/sets will just need to perform pointer arithmetic to get the right value).
After getting stuck a bunch on my previous way I already started a new solution similar to yours. I also thought of another benefit which is that the single pointer will perform better for large matrix sizes as there's one less layer of memory access. 
Thanks a lot for your suggestion! (although *technically* the double pointer method should work, and I'm still interested to know why it doesn't)

Answer (score 1):

Your basic problem is that postfix operators are higher precedence than prefix operators.  So when you say

```
*matA[i] = malloc(matSize * sizeof(int));
```

you are getting

```
*(matA[i]) = malloc(matSize * sizeof(int));
```

when what you want is

```
(*matA)[i] = malloc(matSize * sizeof(int));
```

so you need the explicit parenthesis to make it work.  Similarly, instead of

```
*(int*)matA[i][j] = rand()/RAND_MAX * 10;
```

you need

```
((int**)*matA)[i][j] = rand()/RAND_MAX * 10;
```

Answer (score -1):

The way you're allocating memory is weird.

> `*matA = malloc(matSize * sizeof(int*));`

Where does `matA` point??, unless you allocated some memory and made `matA` point to it outside this function then you are thrashing you memory.

`Malloc` returns a pointer to allocated memory, it doesn't allocate it wherever your random pointer is pointing.

You also don't need three levels of indirection`***matA`, two is enough.

This is your code with the changes I suggested - disclaimer:I didn't actually try this but I think it'll work-:

```
void initMat(int type, int matSize, void ***matA, void ***matB, void ***matC)
{
    int i, j, k;

    switch(type) {
        case 0 :
            *matA = malloc(matSize * sizeof(int*));
            *matB = malloc(matSize * sizeof(int*));
            *matC = malloc(matSize * sizeof(int*));
            for (i = 0; i < matSize; i++) {
                (*matA)[i] = malloc(matSize * sizeof(int));
                (*matB)[i] = malloc(matSize * sizeof(int));
                (*matC)[i] = malloc(matSize * sizeof(int));
                for (j = 0; j < matSize; j++) {
                    (*matA)[i][j] = rand()/RAND_MAX * 10;
                    (*matB)[i][j] = rand()/RAND_MAX * 10;
                    (*matC)[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }
        break;

        case 1 :
        // with float, double, etc.
        break;

        default :
            printf("Invalid case.\n" );
    }
}
```

and when calling:

```
int type,matSize;
//whatever type you like
Type **matA,**matB,**matC; 
//your code here
initMat(type,matSize,&matA,&matB,&matC);
//the rest of your code here
```

Comment: So yea, the reason why just two levels doesn't work is that when you're passing to a function in c, everything is passed by value, so a copy is made. This means changing the value in the function (even though it has the same name) doesn't alter the one in the main. Which is why in c we always pass "one pointer layer up". This is why I had to use 3 levels in the init function, so that the actual two-level matrix retains the value (whether it's an int or a pointer). I have tested this to be true as well.

Comment: This is also why BLUEPIXY's code works, because even though he's only using two levels, the original matA in main is a single pointer, but it's to void, so it doesn't really matter that it disappears when he replaces that void level with pointers to ints. This is why he made an explicitly typed int matrix that is 2-levels in the init function, and linked the pointer to the first level of the passed "void" matrix variable, essentially being 3 levels lower than the passed variable, but with a local reference to it of 2 levels, with explicit type.

Comment: It seems that the place where my original code goes wrong is when I'm setting *matA[i] = malloc(matSize * sizeof(int)); at the second layer (the i-loop). C is interpreting *matA[i] as dereferencing the value at matA[i], whereas I meant for it to be the i-th component of *matA (similar in idea to (*matA)[i]). It seems you can't use both dereferencing and index search together if you want the dereferencing to happen first (which also explains why BLUEPIXY's code used another variable at that level to temporarily replace *matA). It all seems to click together.

Comment: @M.Lee if that's what you are aiming for. you have to make sure that what you pass to this function is and address of the two dimensional array pointer so if we assume your array is `int **matA` and you want to initialize it using this function, then make sure you pass the addess of the pointer when calling it `initMat(type,matSize, &matA, &matB, &matC)`. I'm going to change my answer to reflect these changes.

Comment: yep, I know to do that when calling. Your code there to use (*mat)[i][j] isn't actually recognized by C, so it won't work/compile. I've finished the project now btw. I ended up using a 1-D array for the matrix and using pointer arithmetic for access. This has better performance anyhow. In terms of dynamic typing, I used macros/pre-processing magic to do it instead. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: it should work, see example here https://ideone.com/1aiXcq. However you seem to be done with your project, good job and well done.